# In a JS method, the native DLL method is called. The DLL execution returns, and the the method remaining js code sometimes does not execute?

Tags: javascript, activex, ocx

I have a JS methods , just like :

```
function jsmethods(){
  
  //execute js code
  int i = 0;
  i++;

  //call dlls
  let controller = document.getElementById("ocxControllerId");
  let nativeRes = controller.nativeMethods("some args");
  
  //continue execute js code
  let res = {"nativeResult":nativeRes};
  return res;
 }
```

activeX dll's logic maybe:

```
native nativeRes nativeMethods(){
  show a windows, and this windows have a ok button;
  wait user enter ok button;
  //I can watched after this moment js engine contine execute other js code
  if(user enter ok button){
  // after this moment js engine stop execute js other code
     while(1){
       get hardware statue
       if(statues == value){
          break;
       }
     }
 }
  return nativeRes;
}
```

when I call jsmethdos(),sometimes when native code finished(from the logs),the jsmethods not contine execute remaining js code, and this moment js engine can excute other js methods.I use Vue framwork.